# How to send messages to a customTkinter textbox from a different script

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-text

This might be a very newbie question but I'm struggling to find a solution.

I have a main Python script with a customTkinter window that has a textbox were I post all of my message updates defined:

```
def status_update(self, message):
    self.status_textbox.configure(state="normal")
    self.status_textbox.insert("1.0", message)
    self.status_textbox.configure(state="disabled")
```

Inside my class "class App(customtkinter.CTk):"

The question is, how can I use that status_update function from a separate script that I'm executing inside the cTk class?

Comment: How do you execute the *separate* script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would give the script, e.g. to a class there, an instance of your app. Use the keyword `self` inside App.

random_script.py:

```
class RandomScript:

   def __init__(self, app):
       self.app = app

   def say_hi(self, name):
       text = "Hi " + name
       self.app.stauts_update(text)
```

Somewhere in app.py:

```
from random_script import RandomScript

...

random_script = RandomScript(self)
random_script.say_hi("Pete")
```

Comment: But wouldn't that be creating a separate instance of the app? Because, ideally, I'd like to use the same textbox in both scripts.

Comment: You're within an instance and pass it, or a reference of it, to the script. So there is no copy created.

Comment: Your answer didn' really have the exact answer I was looking for but it did set me on the right path.

The question I should'e asked was "how do I share a class instance between scripts" and that's indeed a very newbie question.

Thanks a lot for your patience and help!

Answer (score 0):

You should define the `status_update` function within whichever script (the "separate script" you mentioned) you main Python file is calling, then import that function into the main file. Always import from the 'bottom up' - your "sub-files" (for lack of a better word) should never call anything defined in your main file.

```
# do this in 'main.py' (or whatever it's called)
from other_file import status_update
```

Comment: I think maybe my description wasn't clear :(

The purpose of the function is to write to a textbox (that the main script creates) to provide updates to the user regarding the status of the current function.

Having the function "status_message" available does not solve the problem since my main issue is that I want to (in realtime) pass messages from one script to the other so that the textbox is as up to date as possible at all times.